# tslint does not exclude files in tsconfig.json when using --project

Tags: tslint

I'm using `--project` to point to my `tsconfig.json`, where I have a `exclude` property like this:

```
"exclude": [
  "foldertoexclude/**/*.ts"
]
```

But, the folder is still being linted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following, and see if it works:

```
{
    // The following will hide the js and map files in the editor
    "files.exclude": {     
        "foldertoexclude":true
     }
}
```

Comment: I apologize, I'm not working on that project anymore so I won't be able to test your code. Thank you anyways!